# MethodInfo.Invoke with custom Class List as parameter

Tags: c#, .net-core, reflection

I'm actually writing a simple application that calls functions of an external DLL's based on a command line.
First I do have a parameter Class that holds all parameters after parsing from command line:

```
public class ParserFunctionParameter
{
    string parameterName = "";
    string parameterValue = "";

    public ParserFunctionParameter(string parameterName, string parameterValue)
    {
        this.parameterName = parameterName;
        this.parameterValue = parameterValue;
    }
}
```

Then I wrote a FunctionLoader Class which basically contains a list of all pre registered DLL's.
A single function within this Class looks like this:

```
public class Function
{
    private Assembly assemblyReference;
    private string functionName;
   
    public Function(Assembly assembly)
    {
        this.assemblyReference = assembly;
        AssemblyName an = assembly.GetName();
        Type type = assembly.GetType(an.Name + ".Class1");
        object o = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        MethodInfo mi = type.GetMethod("GetFunctionName");
        this.functionName = (string)mi.Invoke(o, null);
    }

    public double[] CallFunction(List<ParserFunctionParameter> parameters)
    {
        AssemblyName an = assemblyReference.GetName();
        Type type = assemblyReference.GetType(an.Name + ".Class1");
        object dllClassObject = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        MethodInfo mi = type.GetMethod(functionName);
        object[] objParamArray = { parameters };
        return (double[]) mi.Invoke(dllClassObject, objParamArray);
    }
}
```

So far, this is the application that makes use of the DLL. The DLL itself, looks like this:

```
public class Class1
{
    public string GetFunctionName()
    {
        return "importcsv";
    }

    public double[] importcsv(List<ParserFunctionParameter> parameters)
    {
        // do some stuff depending on parameters 
    }
}
```

Let's assume I use it this way, after I've compiled the DLL to ImportCSV.dll:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<ParserFunctionParameter> par = new List<ParserFunctionParameter>();
        par.Add("file", "C:\test.csv");
        par.Add("skiplines", "1");

        Function func = new Function(Assembly.LoadFile("ImportCSV.dll",)
        double[] result = func.CallFunction(par);
    }
}
```

The (not very helpful) exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[BML.Parser.ParserFunctionParameter]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[BML.Parser.ParserFunctionParameter]'.'
```

How can I pass the List of `ParserFunctionParameter` ?
I've tried simple 'build in' types like string. This works pretty straight forward. But with this 'custom' type this isn't working.

Since this is just a coding for fun project and to check feasibility of a simple plugin interface, I can provide the complete code, if needed.

**Edit:**
Thaks for the comment on the reserved keyword, but that's not causing the exception. This was just an example of calling. I'm sorry for that -> Corrected it.

Thank you.

Comment: params is keyword. Rename params variable name to @params and try again.

Answer (score 1):

You're loading assembly outside of your application context, you also need to use that same assembly and reflection to create its corresponding objects and object method parameters. Otherwise the `ParserFunctionParameter` you have directly referenced in your project is not the same as the one from the assembly you just loaded dynamically. Let me create a simple example and you can apply it to your code.

```
static void Main()
{
    // This is full path to your ImportCSV.dll
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"X:\Absolute\Path\To\ImportCSV.dll");

    // Class1 is the name of your targeted class
    Type classType = assembly.GetType($"{assembly.GetName().Name}.Class1");

    // Your method name is "importcsv"
    MethodInfo methodInfo = classType.GetMethod("importcsv");

    // You know that your method has a single parameter so we can dumb it down here, but
    // you could also do some complex generic reflection type checking and dynamic creation
    ParameterInfo[] methodParameters = methodInfo.GetParameters();
    ParameterInfo onlyParamInfo = methodParameters[0];

    // Since your only parameter is List<ParserFunctionParameter> we need to get its
    // generic type dynamically
    Type genericType = onlyParamInfo.ParameterType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

    // Create an instance of a single parameter, it can be repeated in a loop if you
    // want to add multiple parameters to the list.
    object parserFunctionParameter = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType, "Parameter name", "Parameter value");

    // Create an empty List<ParserFunctionParameter>
    Type listType = typeof(List<>);
    Type parserFunctionParameterListType = listType.MakeGenericType(genericType);
    IList parserFunctionParameterList = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(parserFunctionParameterListType);

    // Add your single instance of ParserFunctionParameter to the list
    parserFunctionParameterList.Add(parserFunctionParameter);

    // Create an instance of your Class1
    object classInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(classType);

    // Invoke its method with parameters
    object result = methodInfo.Invoke(classInstance, new object[] { parserFunctionParameterList });
}
```

Comment: Thank you msmolcic, that was the trick and now it works. 
The only drawback is I have to create new instances for every `ParserFunctionParameter` as you already stated at:
`object parserFunctionParameter = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType, "Parameter name", "Parameter value");` Since this parameter have 2 constructors I have to differ in that loop. But as I already said - great answer. I'll come back on this, when I do have a clue on how to bring back the 'elegance' to this.